# Не читает русский язык

Tags: java, intellij-idea, utf-8, cp1251

Работаю с файлами, мой код:

```java
package com.company;

import java.io.*;
import  java.util.Scanner;

public class Censore {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Stepan\\Список.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Stepan\\Список.txt"), "UTF-8");
        String t = scan.nextLine();
        fr.close();
        System.out.println(t);
        String[] mats = t.split(" ");
        int longarray = mats.length;
        Scanner fx = new Scanner(System.in);
        String stroka = fx.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < longarray; i++) {
            stroka = stroka.replaceAll(mats[i], "*цензура*");
        }
        System.out.println(stroka);
    }
}
```

В файле русские символы. При их считывании Появляются значки �. Видимо тут проблема в кодировке UTF-8. Работаю в Intellij IDEA. Подскажите, как исправить.

Comment: Вот такой код `System.out.println("Опаньки!");` выводит русские буквы?

Comment: И где вы смотрите вывод? В консоли или в IDEA?

Comment: Я смотрю в консоли IDEA. Когда нажимаешь Run

Comment: Проблема именно, когда читается файл, любой код вроде этого System.out.println("Опаньки!"); нормально выводит русские символы

Comment: Возможно, в файле другая кодировка. Попробуйте вместо `"UTF-8"` использовать "windows-1251"

Answer (score 4):

*Стандартная виндовая кодировка - это `CP-1251`.* В `Java` она кодируется как `windows-1251`, поэтому в вашем коде нужно написать так:

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Stepan\\Список.txt"), "windows-1251"));
```

---

Для справки:

```
"ISO-8859-1"   - западноевропейские языки
"windows-1251" - стандартная Windows (русская)
"UTF-8"        - юникод
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это:

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(
        new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("fileNmae"), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Данный метод не работает

Comment: Выводит тот же знак

Answer (score 0):

какая кодировка стоит у текстового файла? можно узнать нотпадом и т.д.
и попробуйте узнать на каком кодировке выдает ИДЕА, можете проверит полученный результат вот тут: http://www.online-decoder.com/ru

и ещё проверьте какая кодировка стоит на самой ИДЕА (Editor -> File Encodings)

Answer (score 0):

ХЗ как исправить, но винда юзает кодировку cp1251, и там руские символы шифруются иными байтами, нежели в utf-8(которая юзается средой разработки в идее так точно), т.е считанные байты нужно переводить в символы с помощью кодировки cp1251

Comment: пробовал запустить из cmd та же фигня

Comment: так а что толку, на сколько я понимаю cmd компилит классы тоже с utf-8, нам надо явно указать cp1251 в коде, либо в сам файл писать в utf-8, + можешь поэксперементировать, запиши в файл что-нить из среды разработки, а потом обратно считай, тогда всё будет ок, инфа 100

Comment: Пришлось текстовый файл перекодировать в utf-8 без BOM и стало считываться корректно.